# Can I just move the library from devDependency to dependencies manually?

Tags: node.js, package.json

I have installed some of my libraries wrongly in dependencies instead of devDependency in my package.json. Can I just move manually by removing the lines in dependencies and add those lines in devDependency? Would that affect anything?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
If you install your environment with

```sh
npm install
```

nothing changes. Otherwise, if you run

```sh
npm install --production
```

that dependencies that you will move to `dev` section won't be installed.

[Useful link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Answer (score 0):

It will not impact unless the dependencies that you are moving from `dependency` to `devDependency` are required on production. As a thumb rule, all packages specified under dependencies are required at runtime. So yes, moving them to devDependencies should effectively break your application if they are required at runtime. If not and they are only used during development, you don't have to bother.